# Re-sizing arrays in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-arrays

So my professor has asked us to read and sort a html file. And in this program we must create a function which resizes three arrays to double their size. This function will be called upon multiple times.

He went over the function in lecture and I followed his notes to write the function.I am confused on what is exactly happening. From looking at my code, wouldn't multiple calls to read functions clear out the temp arrays and result in data being lost and overwritten? My professor has told us to do the resize function using pointer assignment.

Would it makes sense to free the arrays then resize them using

```
(* crn) = (int*)malloc((2*(*size))*sizeof(int));

(* subjects) = (char** )malloc((2*(* size))* sizeof(char*));

(* courses) = (char** )malloc((2*(* size))* sizeof(char*));
```

Then should I copy the data back into the original arrays the same way I did when copying it into temp?

```
  void initialize(int *size, int **crn, char ***subjects, char ***courses)
   {
     int i;

     (*crn) = (int*)malloc((*size)*sizeof(int));
     (*subjects) = (char**)malloc((*size)*sizeof(char*));
     (*courses) = (char**)malloc((*size)*sizeof(char*));

     for(i = 0; i < *size; i++) 
      {
        (*subjects)[i] = (char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char));
        (*courses)[i] = (char*)malloc(6*sizeof(char));
      }
   }

 void resize(int *size, int **crn, char ***subjects, char ***courses)
   {
     int *temp_crn, i;
     char **temp_cour, **temp_subjects;
     temp_crn = (int *)malloc((2*(*size))*sizeof(int));
     temp_cour =(char**)malloc((2*(*size))*sizeof(char*));
     temp_subjects = (char**)malloc((2*(*size))*sizeof(char*));

     for(i = 0; i < 2*(*size); i++)
      {
       temp_subjects[i] = (char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char));
       temp_cour[i] = (char*malloc(6*sizeof(char));
      }

     for(i = 0; i < *size; i++)
       temp_crn[i] = (*crn)[i];

     for(i = 0; i < *size; i++)
       temp_subjects[i] = (*subjects)[i];
       temp_cour[i] = (*courses)[i];

     free(*crn);
     free(*subjects);
     free(*courses);


    *crn = temp_crns;
    *subjects = temp_subjects;
    *courses = temp_cour;

    for(i = *size; i < (2*(*size)); i++)
      (*subjects)[i] = (char*)malloc(4*sizeof(char));
      (*courses)[i] = (char*)malloc(6*sizeof(char));

    *size = *size * 2; 
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You probably need to look at the [`realloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realloc.html) function which resizes previously allocated memory. It copies the old data to the new allocation so you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

To resize arrays you only need to use `realloc` function. It allocates a memory area and copies data from your block into the new memory region, if it is needed.

If you need to write such a function, you need to allocate a new memory area,  copy data to it, maybe using memcpy function or simillar and free the old memory.